# fullPage.js doesnt scroll down from slider

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

Im building a WordPress theme based on fullPage.js Im allmost finishing it. But I have encountered a problem that I cant figure it out.

In the next two examples there is a navigation bar, a first section containing slides and other sections below:

Here http://wordpress-123465.sae1.nitrousbox.com/azal/ scrolling down from the first section that contains slides is smooth and the corresponding link in the navigation bar works (when click scroll up to the slider section)

But here http://wordpress-123465.sae1.nitrousbox.com/azal-beta/ scrolling down is very dificult, also the keyboard doesnt work, after that is imposible to scroll up again, and the navigation bar doesnt work neither.

In both cases pointer in the right side of the screen work.

What could be wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your site contains only one section as a first child of the fullpage.js container.

You probably forgot to close some HTML tags and now you have many sections inside the 1st section. 
Which is not the way fullpage.js works.

Fullpage.js requieres this structure:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

And now you have something like:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to fix HTML errors in your source code.

line 138, you closed `</head>`, it's ok. But you started a `<nav>` tag just after, without opening a `<body>` (which is opened at line 191). This is an error. Nav must be inside body tag

line 234 and 236, opening " character for `style` attribute is missing:

```
<div style=height:12px;">
```

Many div tags are not in the right place. Don't forget you can't do this:

```
<div>
  <p>
  </div>
</p>
```

instead, you must do this:

```
<div>
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

As a good starting point, use a HTML validator to check if your source is correct: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwordpress-123465.sae1.nitrousbox.com%2Fazal%2F%23SliderTitle%2F2&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0